# Linux environment variable using non-fullpath

Tags: environment-variables, shared-library, dynamic-loading

I'm setting the environment variable LD_PRELOAD to a shared library file I created, in order to let LD_PRELOAD to point to my created shared library file, I need to give the full path like this:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=full/path/to/file.so
```

but if I point the LD_PRELOAD to a shared library under `/usr/lib/`, I don't need to give the full path, I don't have root privilege so I cannot put my shared library file to `/usr/lib/`, in such case, how can I set the environment variable LD_PRELOAD using non-fullpath like this:

```
 export LD_PRELOAD=file.so
```

Comment: You could try adding the directory where the library lives to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? One way or another you're going to gave to give a full path *somewhere*, to tell the system how to locate your library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names listed in the `LD_PRELOAD` variable are looked up in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, like library names mentioned in the executable itself. So if you want to preload `/full/path/to/file.so`, you can use

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/full/path/to
export LD_PRELOAD=file.so
```